# Automatically calculating BIC from ictreg model

Tags: r

I looked for a method to calculate the Bayesian Information Criterion (BIC) from a model estimated with `ictreg()` provided by the `list` package but did not find an answer.

Example:

```
library(list)

data(race)

lm.results <- ictreg(y ~ south + age + male + college, data = race, 
                 treat = "treat", J=3, method = "ml")

summary(lm.results)
```

Result:

```
Item Count Technique Regression 

Call: ictreg(formula = y ~ south + age + male + college, data = race, 
    treat = "treat", J = 3, method = "ml")

Sensitive item 
                Est.    S.E.
(Intercept) -5.50833 1.02112
south        1.67564 0.55855
age          0.63587 0.16334
male         0.84647 0.49375
college     -0.31527 0.47360

Control items 
                Est.    S.E.
(Intercept)  1.19141 0.14369
south       -0.29204 0.09692
age          0.03322 0.02768
male        -0.25060 0.08194
college     -0.51641 0.08368

Log-likelihood: -1444.394

Number of control items J set to 3. Treatment groups were indicated by '1' and the control group by '0'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came across. It uses the model to culculate the BIC using the following formula: `-2*log-likelihood + npar*log(nobs)`, where npar represents the number of parameters and nobs the number of observations in the fitted model

The following function calculates the BIC:

```
bic_ictreg <- function(fit) {
  # Check if method is "ml". Stop if not.
  if(fit[["method"]] != "ml") {
    stop("Function needs a model that uses the Expectation-Maximization algorithm to estimate. Use method = 'ml' within ictreg")
  }

  # Calculate BIC
  -2*fit[["llik"]] + (length(fit[["par.treat"]]) + 
                        length(fit[["par.control"]])) * 
    log(length(fit[["pred.post"]]))
}

bic_ictreg(lm.results)
```

Example from above:

```
library(list)

data(race)

lm.results <- ictreg(y ~ south + age + male + college, data = race, 
                 treat = "treat", J=3, method = "ml")

bic_ictreg(lm.results)
```

Result:

```
[1] 2959.797
```

The result is consistent with the BIC reported by Blair & Imai (2012, p. 70).

Reference

Blair, G., & Imai, K. (2012). Statistical Analysis of List Experiments. *Political Analysis*, 20(01), 47–77. https://doi.org/10.1093/pan/mpr048